# Pass a .js file to mongo db.eval()

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get [variety](https://github.com/variety/variety) working with `db.eval()` instead of commandline `--eval`. This is because I get some problems with authentication.

The normal use is from the commandline:

```
$ mongo test --eval "var collection = 'users', maxDepth = 3" /path/to/variety.js
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
$ mongo
>> use admin
>> db.auth("foo", "bar")
>> use anotherColl
>> db.eval("/path/to/variety.js", "var collection = 'users', maxDepth = 3")
>> Thu Mar  7 13:19:10 uncaught exception: {
    "errmsg" : "compile failed: JS Error: SyntaxError: invalid flag after regular expression nofile_a:0",
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Is there a way to have `db.eval()` eat an javascript file instead of an string?

Comment: I believe you can only shove a js file into the command of the `mongo` program atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Sammaye and my gut feeling you can't put in .js files in `db.eval()`. However for variety there is an solution described [here](https://github.com/variety/variety/pull/17).

```
mongo -u USER-p PASS admin --eval "var collection = 'COL', db_name='DB_NAME'" variety.js
```

And now the [authentication problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272521/command-line-authentication-of-mongo-fails) :(