# command line authentication of mongo fails

Tags: mongodb

I am running mongo 2.2.2 on osx.

When I do the following authentication is going fine:

```
$ mongo
>> use admin
>> db.auth("uname", "password")
```

log:

```
Thu Mar  7 13:51:08 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63474 #10 (4 connections now open)
Thu Mar  7 13:51:08 [conn10]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "123", user: "uname", key: "456" }
```

However when I try to authenticate directly from the commandline:

```
$ mongo admin -u uname -p password
```

I get the following error:

```
Thu Mar  7 14:25:52 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63939 #12 (5 connections now open)
Thu Mar  7 14:25:52 [conn12]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "789", user: "uname", key: "147" }
Thu Mar  7 14:25:52 [conn12] auth: key mismatch uname, ns:admin
Thu Mar  7 14:25:52 [conn12] end connection 127.0.0.1:63939 (4 connections now open)
```

Does anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

A password containing special characters, especially the dollar sign, has to be put in single quotes to protect them from the command shell:

```
$ mongo admin -u uname -p 'password'
```

Comment: As explained [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/)

Comment: To prevent exposing password to bash history, use `mongo admin -u uname -p` which will prompt you the password

Comment: @Kimmo Your comment is an answer in its own right. The password prompt you get with `-p` does not require protecting/escaping special characters, so the password can just be entered with no quote marks. I'll upvote that answer, which includes the added security bonus!

Comment: could not imagine how much official documents is confusing for this basic command!

Comment: I needed to put the password in double quotation marks, single did not work

Answer (score 60):

You have to use the `--authenticationDatabase` to indicate mongodb where to find the user you have created. For example:

```
mongo admin -u uname -p 'password' --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: The above command has to be run exactly as it is, barring the value for `uname` and `password`.

Answer (score 2):

**This is the way to access an authenticate MongoDB database from terminal**

```
mongo -u user_name -p "your_password" host_name/database_name
```

**Ex:**

```
mongo -u hasib -p "123456" localhost/my_db
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also connect using the mongo connection URL as follow:

```
mongo "mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host: 127.0.0.1>:<port: 27017>/<db_name>?authSource=admin"
```

- The db_name is optional.
- The host is usually 127.0.0.1 if you are
  connection to localhost.
- The port is usually 27017.

Answer (score -8):

To Login to MongoDB Via Command Line do the following

```
$ mongo admin -u 'username' -p 'Password'
```

Comment: Your exact same response has been given on 2013!