# Password flag doesn't work to log into mongo

Tags: mongodb

I created a mongo daemon.
Then, I did:

```
$ mongo --port 27017

> use admin
> db.createUser({
           user: "AzureDiamond",
            pwd: "hunter2",
          roles: [{
               role: "readWrite",
                 db: "test_db1"
          }]
   })
>^D
```

Then I tried to log into Mongo with the new account ([exactly as in section 7 of Mongo's utorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)):

```
$ mongo --port 27017 -u "AzureDiamond" -p "hunter2" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

This is the weird part. It still prompted me for my password, and then appended that to the database path that I connected to:

```
Enter password:
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/hunter2
>
```

What did I do wrong? How can I connect to Mongo while supplying the password in the command line, but not having my  password displayed on the screen?

Comment: Are there any characters in your password which might be confusing things, for example a double-quote character or a backslash?

Comment: What version of shell are you using ? Are you running shell on unix environment ?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11. Running on Debian 9

Comment: The `connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/hunter2` portion suggests that your mongo client is trying to connect to a database named 'hunter2'. This indicates that the shell is interpreting 'hunter2' as the database option, e.g. `mongo --port 1234 -u myuser -p mypass --authenticationDatabase admin hunter2`. Vince's suggestion of special characters in a username or password seems a likely candidate. You may also want to check your mongodb.log file for any auth failures.

Comment: [This](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32421) seems related to your issue. Remove the space between the flag and password as suggested in the jira comments.

Comment: Good question! +1 for it. Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is just a typo that you've pointed out in your question, Can you please retry the command as shown below:

> You just missed a **d** in your username!

```
$ mongo --port 27017 -u "AzureDiamond" -p "hunter2" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

If this doesn't work, can you please try logging in to Mongo database as per the documentation provided ***[here](https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb-shell/)***.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My username and password are not actually `AzureDiamond` and `hunter2`.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Did you, by any chance tried the version that I suggested in the link?

Comment: Yes, the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
mongo admin -u {username} -p '{password}'
```

Ref: [command line authentication of mongo fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272521/command-line-authentication-of-mongo-fails)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [connection string URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)?

e.g. `mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]`

So in your case, 
`mongo mongodb://AzureDiamond:hunter2@localhost:27017/test_db1?authSource=admin`

Answer (score 0):

### Easiest and Most Secure way:

---

You don't need to specify the port, you can do it easily using:

```
mongo admin -u ""AzureDiamond"" -p
```

Now it will prompt you for the password, **enter your password** and Voila!! You are logged in!

This is the most secure way, as your password is not visible to others as well.

***Hope this works for you! Let me know if this doesn't work!***

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in 3.2.11.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32421

> Thank you for the report. After some testing, I'm able to reproduce this issue and am investigating the cause. However, as a workaround it appears that if you do not leave a space between the -p flag and the password, it logs in as expected

So try `-u UserName -pPassword`