# mongodb query using single command within mongodbs windows cli

Tags: windows, mongodb, command-line-interface

I'm trying to execute a mongodb query in a single command so I can run a batch script from within windows software. The mongodb database is already built, here are my windows console commands and cli query that work:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongo ds045565-a1.mongolab.com:45565/heroku_mydatabase
2017-09-01T09:14:05.196+0100 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: ds045565-a1.mongolab.com:45565/heroku_mydatabase
rs-ds045565:PRIMARY> db.auth("myusername","mypassword");db.getCollection('94081_DS_FuelNBS').find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ab4ae3bc5cf82663236b4f"), "code" : "D", "description" : "Diesel", "lastModified" : ISODate("2017-02-20T20:00:35.680Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ab4ae3bc5cf82663236b50"), "code" : "H", "description" : "Hydrogen", "lastModified" : ISODate("2017-02-20T20:00:35.680Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ab4ae3bc5cf82663236b51"), "code" : "P", "description" : "Petrol", "lastModified" : ISODate("2017-02-20T20:00:35.680Z") }
rs-ds045565:PRIMARY> exit
bye
```

If I then try to execute as a single windows command I do not get any response output other than the error messages:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongo ds045565-a1.mongolab.com:45565/heroku_mydatabase mymongodbcommands.txt > output.txt
```

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>

Here is the contents of mymongodbcommands.txt and output.txt

mymongodbcommands.txt:

```
db.auth("myusername","mypassword");db.getCollection('94081_DS_FuelNBS').find({})
```

output.txt

```
2017-09-01T09:15:41.604+0100 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: ds045565-a1.mongolab.com:45565/heroku_mydatabase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider [Scripts for Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#scripting) - this is correct way of doing what you want

As example for your case:

```
mongo ds045565-a1.mongolab.com:45565/heroku_mydatabase -u myusername -p mypassword --eval "var c = db.getCollection('94081_DS_FuelNBS').find(); while(c.hasNext()) {printjson(c.next())}"
```

You can further build your own `mymongodbcommands.js` and pass it like:

```
mongo host:port/db mymongodbcommands.js > output.txt
```

whereas js file will contain both authentication and your desired bunch of commands

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271176/pass-a-js-file-to-mongo-db-eval) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028235/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-from-bash) answers to similar question.

Comment: Thanks Kostiantyn, this now just appears to spit out js code!....     
2017-09-01T10:00:03.343+0100 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: ds045565-a1.mongolab.com:45565/heroku_ltpz6v5f
{
 "_mongo" : connection to ds045565-a1.mongolab.com:45565,
 "_db" : heroku_ltpz6v5f,
 "_collection" : heroku_ltpz6v5f.94081_DS_FuelNBS,
 "_ns" : "heroku_ltpz6v5f.94081_DS_FuelNBS",
 "_query" : {
  
 },
 "_fields" : null,
 "_limit" : 0,
 "_skip" : 0,

Comment: Looks like syntax of commands passed to eval is not correct. Try `-- eval "var c = db.getCollection('94081_DS_FuelNBS').find(); while(c.hasNext()) {printjson(c.next())}"` I've updated answer accordingly

Comment: It works, you are a genius and your boss should promote you. Many thanks